# How to disable / uninstall Ubuntu On Screen keyboard

Tags: 22.04, keyboard

I've been using Ubuntu 22.04.03 for some time.

I've developed a PyQt6 desktop application that I will be using on a Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga with a touch screen.  I've enabled the on-screen keyboard that doesn't appear to work properly.  It pops up randomly and doesn't when I'm on an input field.

I've since installed another OSK (onboard) and have found it has a full keyboard layout and works perfectly for me.

Can someone show me how to remove the default OSK?

[image: default OSK]

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue by installing gnome extensions and then installing the improved OSK (supported one).

Once installed configure the OSK to ignore touch input (which I wanted).

The improved version appears to work properly, doesn't popup randomly as the default does, has a full keyboard and is displayed by swiping from the bottom of the touch screen (same as default).